# Patroni Cluster Switchover Assistance

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, patroni

I am trying to create an automated shell script that will perform a patroni switchover. This will promote a leader within a 3-node cluster, and then reboot the replicas. I have a curl command that can perform the switchover for the leader. But I am not sure how to automate a reboot for the other two replicas? Or how that will be structured. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in Bash right now. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Have you read [this](https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_api.html#restart-endpoint)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.